# How old is Mr. Mxyzptlk?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe

Is there anything in canon (preferably referring to comics Mxyzptlk) that speaks to the age of this 5th-dimensional being?

Answer (score 1):

In [*Superman: Whatever Happened to the Man of Tomorrow?*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman:_Whatever_Happened_to_the_Man_of_Tomorrow%3F), we learn that Mxyzptlk is 6000(ish) years old.

> **Mister Mxyzptlk:** The big problem with being immortal is filling your time. For example, **I spent the first two thousand years of my existence** doing absolutely nothing.
>
> **Mister Mxyzptlk:** Eventually, simple inertia became tiresome, so **I spent the next two thousand years** being saintly and benign, doing only good deeds. When that novelty began to fade, I decided to try being mischievous.
>
> **Mister Mxyzptlk:** **Now, two thousand years later,** I'm bored again. I need a change. Starting with your death, I shall spend the next two millennia being evil!

[image: Comic page, relevant parts quoted above]

Comment: Downvoted.
The OP asks quite clearly for something in canon; this story is completely out of canon, as it was written and produced for the Elsewhere line of comics which are all officially, explicitly, intentionally non canon.

Comment: @JackBNimble - Inert for 2000 years, good for 2000 years, mischievous for 2000 years.

Comment: Ah i only read what you put in quote blocks not the image, you omitted where he says he became mischievous next, so the way those blocks read he is only 4000

Comment: @JackBNimble - Blame Carrot. He added the (incomplete) block quotes. You just can't get the staff these days...

Answer (score 0):

Probably impossible to state by virtue of his being a fifth dimensional imp.

> The Fifth Dimension is an inter-dimensional reality that exists outside of the normally accepted space/time continuum.  - https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Fifth_Dimension

Since he comes from a place with with different rules for time, he could be any age.

Comment: Do you have a better source for this than a fan written wiki?